# How to properly parse a file in python, and save its contents to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, parsing

So I have the following file summary1:

```
---
Project: pgm1
Last-Status: success
summary:  102 passed, 88 warnings in 26.11s
---
Project: pgm2
Last-Status: failed
summary:  1 failed, 316 passed, 204 warnings in 2919.10s
---
Project: pgm3
Last-Status: success
summary:  400 passed, 40 skipped, 1 xfailed in 3.17s
---
```

And I need to parse it's contents, and then in a loop, create a dictionary with pre-defined values, and then populate the corresponding dictionary keys, with the parsed values from the file, resulting in something like this:

```
entry =  {
              "{#STATUS}": 0
              "{#DESCRIPTION}": "pgm2",
              "{#PASSED}": 316,
              "{#FAILED}": 1,
              "{#WARNING}": 204,
              "{#SKIPPED}": 0,
              "{#XFAILED}": 0,
              "{#DURATION}": 2919.10
}...
```

And so on for all data sections in the file.
**However, I am not able to obtain and print the proper value for the field "{#DURATION}".  Instead, this is what I get:**

```
 {
  "{#PASSED}": "316",
  "{#FAILED}": "1",
  "{#DURATION}": "10",
  "{#XFAILED}": 0,
  "{#SKIPPED}": 0,
  "{#STATUS}": 0,
  "{#DESCRIPTION}": "pmg2",
  "{#WARNING}": 204
 }
```

And here is my code:

```
def break_text(lst_text):
    desc = re.findall(r": (.*)", lst_text[1])
    status = re.findall(r": (.*)", lst_text[2])
    summary = re.findall(r"\d+ \w+", lst_text[3])
    return desc, status, summary


def create_dict(lst):
    desc = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in lst[0]])
    status = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in lst[1]])
    if status == "success":
        status = 1
    else:
        status = 0

entry = {
    "{#STATUS}": status,
    "{#DESCRIPTION}": desc,
    "{#PASSED}": 0,
    "{#FAILED}": 0,
    "{#WARNING}": 0,
    "{#SKIPPED}": 0,
    "{#XFAILED}": 0,
    "{#DURATION}": 0,
}
dict_temp = {
    "passed": "{#PASSED}",
    "failed": "{#FAILED}",
    "warnings": "{#WARNING}",
    "skipped": "{#SKIPPED}",
    "xfailed": "{#XFAILED}",
    "seconds": "{#DURATION}",
}
for i in lst[2]:
    v, k = i.split()
    entry[dict_temp[k]] = v
return entry


with open("/tmp/summary1", "r") as file:
    file = file.read().splitlines()

data_list = []

for i in range(0, len(file), 4):  # Read 4 lines of the file each time
    text = file[i: i + 4]
    if len(text) <= 1:
        continue
    res_tmp = break_text(text)
    res = create_dict(res_tmp)
    data_list.append(res)

new_dict = dict()
new_dict["data"] = data_list

print(new_dict)
```

**Any suggestions on how to get the proper value for the field "{#DURATION}" and what is wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example to parse the text:

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

txt = """
---
Project: pgm1
Last-Status: success
summary:  102 passed, 88 warnings in 26.11s
---
Project: pgm2
Last-Status: failed
summary:  1 failed, 316 passed, 204 warnings in 2919.10s
---
Project: pgm3
Last-Status: success
summary:  400 passed, 40 skipped, 1 xfailed in 3.17s
---
"""

project = re.findall(r"Project: (.*)", txt)
last_status = re.findall(r"Last-Status: (.*)", txt)
summary = re.findall(r"summary:(.*)", txt)

entries = []
for p, l, s in zip(project, last_status, summary):
    d = dict([(b, a) for a, b in re.findall(r"([\d+.]+)\s+?([a-z]+)", s)])
    entries.append(
        {
            "{#STATUS}": int(l == "success"),
            "{#DESCRIPTION}": p,
            "{#PASSED}": int(d.get("passed", 0)),
            "{#FAILED}": int(d.get("failed", 0)),
            "{#WARNING}": int(d.get("warnings", 0)),
            "{#SKIPPED}": int(d.get("skipped", 0)),
            "{#XFAILED}": int(d.get("xfailed", 0)),
            "{#DURATION}": float(re.search(r"([\d.]+)s\s*$", s).group(1)),
        }
    )


pprint(entries)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'{#DESCRIPTION}': 'pgm1',
  '{#DURATION}': 26.11,
  '{#FAILED}': 0,
  '{#PASSED}': 102,
  '{#SKIPPED}': 0,
  '{#STATUS}': 1,
  '{#WARNING}': 88,
  '{#XFAILED}': 0},
 {'{#DESCRIPTION}': 'pgm2',
  '{#DURATION}': 2919.1,
  '{#FAILED}': 1,
  '{#PASSED}': 316,
  '{#SKIPPED}': 0,
  '{#STATUS}': 0,
  '{#WARNING}': 204,
  '{#XFAILED}': 0},
 {'{#DESCRIPTION}': 'pgm3',
  '{#DURATION}': 3.17,
  '{#FAILED}': 0,
  '{#PASSED}': 400,
  '{#SKIPPED}': 40,
  '{#STATUS}': 1,
  '{#WARNING}': 0,
  '{#XFAILED}': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
summary = re.findall(r"\d+ \w+", lst_text[3])
```

The regex that extracts the summary does not account for decimal points and also expects a space between a number and word. I'm not sure how to correct the regex, but this is a solution that can temporarily give you the desired output.

```
summary = re.findall(r"\d+ \w+", lst_text[3])
summary += [re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", lst_text[3])[0] + " seconds"]
```

Comment: I get the following error if I add that line of code :   
File "python4.py", line 36, in break_text
    summary += [re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", lst_text[3])[0] + " seconds"]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That would mean, that it couldn't find the duration matching the regex in this case. I'm sorry I don't know much about regex. I would recheck the regex you have to find the summary to also include floating point numbers.